# size of Images in tableviewcell

Tags: iphone

Can any one tell me the standard size of the Images that would appear on the left side of a TableView Cell.

Comment: hi ...
i am new to this forum.. i dont know how to accept answer... how can i do that.... Pls explain

Comment: Yes, people have taken the time to provide 11 answers for you and you've accepted none of them. Go back and hit the check mark next to any of the answers that helped you resolve your previous problems. Its just polite to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the default is 40x32. The default cell height is 44 pixels and the images are just under that.

Of course, the display size has nothing to do with the size of the actual image object. You can display enormous images in a little bitty image views.

Answer (score 0):

You can always just check the size of the image view frame for one of your cells that has an image.

```
CGFloat imageHeight = someCell.imageView.frame.size.height;
CGFloat imageWidth = someCell.imageView.frame.size.width;
```

I haven't tried this out but it might give you what you want.